# Creating custom 'test' command to run a test suite for a Flask application

Tags: python-3.x, testing, flask, flask-cli

We are extending the Flask-cli with some custom commands. The command `test` is one of them:

```
# run.py: specified by FLASK_APP
# This is the Flask application object
app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_ENV') or 'default')

@app.cli.command()
def test():
    """Run the unit tests."""
        
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')

    test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    test_runner.run(tests)
```

However a typical test (using Python's built-in unittest module) looks like
this which is based on the style described [here](http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/unit-testing-a-flask-application/).

```
# some-tests.py: unittest-based test case.
class SomeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_load(self):
        pass
```

I am clearly hitting an anti-pattern here: I have initialized a flask object with the default(`development`) configuration because I need it for the `@app.cli.command()` decorator which all happens in `run.py`. However once I run the test setUp function in `some-tests.py` I somehow have to obtain a Flask object utilizing the `testing` configuration, e.g. by recreating a Flask app with the `testing` configuration like what happens now.

I would like to have pointers on how one goes about to implement a `flask-cli` test command in which only one `Flask` object is created which is reused amongst the various test cases without having the need of explicitely setting the environment to `testing` before I run `flask test` on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this answer will suit your requirements but that is how I would try to approach this problem. Unfortunately, if you want to use default CLI interface in Flask than you need to call `create_app` just to call `flask test` command. What you can do is try use `pytest`. It allows you to create fixtures that can be used across multiple test cases. For example, in your `tests` package create file named `conftest.py` and declare some default fixtures like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    return create_app('testing')


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture
def database(app):
    _db.app = app

    with app.app_context():
        _db.create_all()

    yield _db

    _db.session.close()
    _db.drop_all()
```

Then in your test case file (ex. test_login.py) you can use those fixtures like this:

```py
# Notice argument names are the same as name of our fixtures
# You don't need to import fixtures to this file - pytest will  
# automatically recognize fixtures for you
def test_registration(app, client):
    response = client.post(
        '/api/auth/login',
        json={
            'username': 'user1',
            'password': '$dwq3&jNYGu'
        })
    assert response.status_code == 200
    json_data = response.get_json()
    assert json_data['access_token']
    assert json_data['refresh_token']
```

The best thing about this approach is that you don't need to create `setUp` and `tearDown` methods. Then you can create `test` cli command for your app:

```py
import pytest

@app.cli.command()
def test():
    '''
    Run tests.
    '''
    pytest.main(['--rootdir', './tests'])
```

And call it like this `flask test`.

Comment: found it useful. small question, how do you publish results using this approach? for e.g. something like --junitxml results.xml

Comment: @RajatArora I think you should checkout pytest docs to see if there is flag for this.